# Rails form_for ignoring ":remote => true'" after first ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, form-for

OK guys this one has had me frustrated for a few hours now.  I've searched and can't seem to find anyone else having a similar issue.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I am trying to make an AJAX call to my controller to update a line_item's quantity property.  The code is as follows:

```
###Controller update action###

def update
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  @quote = @line_item.quote
  respond_with(@line_item, @quote) do |format|
    if @line_item.update_attributes(params[:line_item])
      format.html  { redirect_to(@quote,
                    :notice => 'Quantity was successfully updated.')}
      format.js
    else
      format.html  { redirect_to(@quote,
                    :notice => 'Oops!  James messed up again.')}
      format.js  { render 'shared/update_error' }
    end
  end
end

#####View code######

- @quote.line_items.each do |item|
    = form_for item, :remote => true do |f|
      %tr
        %td.quantity_cell
          = f.text_field :quantity, :size => 2
          = image_submit_tag("update_quantity_button.png", :id => "quantity_update")

####Javascript for the callback####

$("#quote_show_parts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/show_quote') %>");
```

---

The problem is that the first request will work as expected.  the call is executed, record updated, and the change reflected on the page.  Checking the page source, you can see the "_method ... 'put'" hidden tag in the form.

if i change the value in the field and hit the button again, i get a routing error:

```
Started POST "/line_items/90" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-08 15:11:45 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/line_items/90"):
```

Now, it seems as though the _method tag (still there when checking the page source) is being ignored and a POST call being made.  Either way a POST route is defined for that URL so i'm not sure why the "no route" error would happen.  if i remove the ':remote => true' the functionality works as expected and there are no issues.

Thank you all very much is advance.

EDIT: added model code:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :quote

  def total_price(company)
    part.price(company) * quantity
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with validation in the model. Could you share that?

Comment: does the partial re-draw the form?

Comment: yes, it does.  it uses the javascript callback to re-render the partial that contains the form.

Comment: rails version? jQuery or Prototype?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?